# Is there a way to upload to S3 from a url using node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, upload, knox-amazon-s3-client

I found this question, but it doesn't seem to answer my question as I think it's still talking about local files.

I want to take, say, and [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) link and upload it to S3 using node. Is [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) capable of this or do I need to use something else?

Not sure where to get started.

Comment: many answers indicate that the "accepted" answer might not be the correct one, this might need updating and upvoting other relevant answers. There is, of course, no obligation to do so though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I’m not using [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) but the official [AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-intro.html). I issue a request to a URL with `{encoding: null}` in order to retrieve the data in buffer which can be passed directly to the `Body` parameter for `s3.putObject()`. Here below is an example of putting a remote image in a bucket with [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) and [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var request = require('request');

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

function put_from_url(url, bucket, key, callback) {
    request({
        url: url,
        encoding: null
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err)
            return callback(err, res);

        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key,
            ContentType: res.headers['content-type'],
            ContentLength: res.headers['content-length'],
            Body: body // buffer
        }, callback);
    })
}

put_from_url('http://a0.awsstatic.com/main/images/logos/aws_logo.png', 'your_bucket', 'media/aws_logo.png', function(err, res) {
    if (err)
        throw err;

    console.log('Uploaded data successfully!');
});
```

Comment: Exactly same approach I took. My image files get corrupted on S3 :(

Comment: +1 for the example. My approach was also similar to this but I was having corrupt upload issues. This code seems to be working for me though.

Comment: If you use axios - set header responseType: 'stream'

Comment: This worked for me. To avoid the corrupt image issue, I had to ensure the `encoding: null` was set in the request options

Comment: @Alexander, your comment really helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

For those that are looking for a solution that `doesn't involves callbacks`, and prefeers `promises`, based on @micmia code here is an alternative:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
request = require('request');


const bucketName='yourBucketName';
const bucketOptions = {...Your options};
var s3 = new AWS.S3(options);

function UploadFromUrlToS3(url,destPath){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {            
        request({
            url: url,
            encoding: null
        }, function(err, res, body) {        
            if (err){
                reject(err);
            }
            var objectParams = {
                ContentType: res.headers['content-type'],
                ContentLength: res.headers['content-length'],
                Key: destPath,
                Body: body 
            };
            resolve(s3.putObject(objectParams).promise());
        });
    });
}

UploadFromUrlToS3(
    'http://a0.awsstatic.com/main/images/logos/aws_logo.png',
    'your/s3/path/aws_logo.png' )
    .then(function() {
        console.log('image was saved...');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('image was not saved!',err);
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

Building on @Yuri's post, for those who would like to use `axios` instead of `request` & ES6 syntax for a more modern approach + added the required `Bucket` property to `params` (and it downloads any file, not only images):

```js
const uploadFileToS3 = (url, bucket, key) => {
  return axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer", responseEncoding: "binary" }).then((response) => {
    const params = {
      ContentType: response.headers["content-type"],
      ContentLength: response.data.length.toString(), // or response.header["content-length"] if available for the type of file downloaded
      Bucket: bucket,
      Body: response.data,
      Key: key,
    };
    return s3.putObject(params).promise();
  });
}

uploadFileToS3(<your_file_url>, <your_s3_path>, <your_s3_bucket>)
   .then(() => console.log("File saved!"))
   .catch(error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 3):

Same thing as the above answer but with fetch:

```
async function upload(url: string, key: string, bucket: string) {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type") ?? undefined;
  const contentLength =
    response.headers.get("content-length") != null
      ? Number(response.headers.get("content-length"))
      : undefined;

  return s3
    .putObject({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
      ContentType: contentType,
      ContentLength: contentLength,
      Body: response.body, // buffer
    })
    .promise();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. There's an example of doing this in the knox README

```
http.get('http://google.com/doodle.png', function(res){
  var headers = {
      'Content-Length': res.headers['content-length']
    , 'Content-Type': res.headers['content-type']
  };
  client.putStream(res, '/doodle.png', headers, function(err, res){
    // Logic
  });
});
```

Comment: There's no reason to be sarcastic and rude.